# Snabbdom - can not add TR to top of table with out full re-render of rows

Tags: html, list, dom, virtual, rerender

I'm trying to add and remove Table Rows to a Table with out rerendering all rows that have not been modified. When I add rows to the end of the table, the existing row do not get rerendered and the new rows are added to the view. However, when I add rows to the beginning of the table (rows), all of the rows rerender including the rows not modified. I've check the HTML and all existing rows are exactly the same before and after the addition.

is this due to how snabbdom conducts its diff? top down approach? I've seen this same type of logic in per DIV format with out any issues. any insight into this would be really great, or any ideas how I could further debug this other than just conducting a simply html diff.

I'm suspecting its this code that might be causing this behavior.
https://github.com/snabbdom/snabbdom/blob/60c604159038680cdd70d9725d2a209746569bb8/src/init.ts#L318

can anyone sanity check me?

Answer (score 0):

In my findings ,answer to this question is strictly how snabbdom is implemented. The framework that implements the patching is where  the answer to this diffing and patching occurs.